# Postgres Group by consecutive events, breaking when there is more then a 10 minute gap

Tags: sql, postgresql

So say I have a table with:

```
id | type | timemstamp
1  | 'dog' | '2019-01-01T12:00:00Z'
2  | 'cat' | '2019-01-01T12:01:00Z'
3  | 'dog' | '2019-01-01T12:02:00Z'
4  | 'dog' | '2019-01-01T12:03:00Z'
5  | 'cat' | '2019-01-01T12:03:00Z'
6  | 'dog' | '2019-01-01T12:15:00Z'
```

I'd want see:

```
starttime | endtime | count | type
'2019-01-01T12:00:00Z', '2019-01-01T12:03:00Z', 3, 'dog'
'2019-01-01T12:01:00Z', '2019-01-01T12:03:00Z', 2, 'cat'
'2019-01-01T12:14:00Z', '2019-01-01T12:14:00Z', 1, 'dog'
```

EDIT:

To clarify im basically looking for it to group by activity in cluster, where a cluster is defined as continious activity within a 10 minute period.

So in the above example, the first `dog` cluster has a count of three because it has 3 rows in a 10 minute period without more then 10 minutes between each row.

Comment: What are the rules for combining rows.  It is not obvious.

Comment: It is unclear: do you want to get series in 10 minutes or series where each event not more then 10 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()` to get the previous timestamp.  Then a cumulative count of where the previous gap is more than 10 minutes . . . and finally, aggregation:

```
select min(timestamp), max(timestamp), count(*), type
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where prev_ts < timestamp - interval '10 minute') over (partition by type order by timestamp) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(timestamp) over (partition by type order by timestamp) as prev_ts
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by type, grp
order by type, min(timestamp)
```

This does not generate exactly the results you have in the question, but it might be what you really want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4d4b284d3bbe791b0bfb3b63b6c29d1f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

It was the challenge :)

```
with recursive c as (
    (
        select
            type,
            min(timestamp) as timestamp,
            '0'::interval as dt,
            1 as cl
        from t group by type) union all
    (
        select distinct on (t.type)
            t.type,
            t.timestamp,
            case when dt + (t.timestamp - c.timestamp) > '10 min'::interval then '0'::interval else dt + (t.timestamp - c.timestamp) end,
            case when dt + (t.timestamp - c.timestamp) > '10 min'::interval then cl + 1 else cl end
        from t join c on (t.type = c.type and t.timestamp > c.timestamp)
        order by t.type, t.timestamp))
select
    min(timestamp) as starttime,
    max(timestamp) as endtyime,
    count(*) as "count",
    "type"
from c
group by "type", cl
order by 1;

┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬──────┐
│      starttime      │      endtyime       │ count │ type │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────┼──────┤
│ 2019-01-01 12:00:00 │ 2019-01-01 12:03:00 │     3 │ dog  │
│ 2019-01-01 12:01:00 │ 2019-01-01 12:03:00 │     2 │ cat  │
│ 2019-01-01 12:15:00 │ 2019-01-01 12:15:00 │     1 │ dog  │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴──────┘
```

Hope you are familiar with recursive CTEs.

Brief explanation:

The `dt` column keeps the interval from the last "check point" to the current time. When it is greater the 10 min then it resets to 0.

The `cl` column keeps the "cluster number". When `dt` is greater then 10 min then it increases.

Finally we are finding the min and max timestamp as start and end time and the count of rows for each type and "cluster".

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ae8b94d92b7e51dec6976cdc23600f6b)